# Getting exit code from a batch file

Tags: c#

In C#, how can I capture the exit code of batch file I launch via Process.Start()?

Also, is there any limitation of running a batch file via Windows Service (The service being the invoker)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process.Start() returns a Process instance. Process has an ExitCode property.

Answer (score 6):

Sample:

```
Process prc = Process.Start(@"C:\file.bat");
prc.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = prc.ExitCode;
```

If you will try to start some process that interacts with UI from Windows Service you will run into a "[Services isolation in Session 0](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx)" problem.